# shell script to set the suid bit as root user

Tags: linux, shell, suid

I need a Shell script, this shell script should : 
    1. create another shell script
    2. set the suid bit for new script as a root user
    3. run this new script as current user

Can we do this?
anyone can give any idea or some code snippets?

Comment: Isn't this something that sudo is best suited for ?  I have always found suid disabled for script files.

Comment: Take care not to give anyone write access to the setuid shell script. Otherwise anyone is able to gain full root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work under many versions of unix (or linux).   The setuid bit on shell scripts is typically ignored, since it is far too easy to subvert such a program.